# Im storing the image in the database but is replaced

Tags: java, android, mysql

I'm running simple code here with volley, the code just uploads a picture that is taken from my phone to the database in my web server.

This is my main activity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button;
    private String encoded_string, image_name;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private File file;
    private Uri file_uri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                getFileUri();
                i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file_uri);
                startActivityForResult(i, 10);
            }
        });
    }

    private void getFileUri() {
        image_name = "testing123.jpg";

        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                + File.separator + image_name
        );

        file_uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 10 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            new Encode_image().execute();
        }
    }

    private class Encode_image extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file_uri.getPath());
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, stream);
            bitmap.recycle();

            byte[] array = stream.toByteArray();
            encoded_string = Base64.encodeToString(array, 0);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            makeRequest();
        }
    }

    private void makeRequest() {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://mysite/connection.php",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("encoded_string",encoded_string);
                map.put("image_name",image_name);

                return map;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

Ok, I have this issue for now, when I upload a pic, i know it will be uploaded to the image folder in my web server, but it will be uploading the image with the name testing123.jpg  , if I take another photo it stores to the database but in my image folder it will not create but replace my existing testing123.jpg with the new image, what I want is when I take a photo it stores the pic but with a diferent name, or the name that the phone provides by itself for the photo, I know the error is happening here

```
 private void getFileUri() {
            image_name = "testing123.jpg";

            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                    + File.separator + image_name
            );

            file_uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        }
```

My connection.php

```
<?php
 header('Content-type : bitmap; charset=utf-8');

 if(isset($_POST["encoded_string"])){

    $encoded_string = $_POST["encoded_string"];
    $image_name = $_POST["image_name"];

    $decoded_string = base64_decode($encoded_string);

    $path = 'images/'.$image_name;

    $file = fopen($path, 'wb');

    $is_written = fwrite($file, $decoded_string);
    fclose($file);

    if($is_written > 0) {

        $connection = mysqli_connect('mysql.host', 'user', 'pass','db');
        $query = "INSERT INTO photos(name,path) values('$image_name','$path');";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) ;

        if($result){
            echo "success";
        }else{
            echo "failed";
        }

        mysqli_close($connection);
    }
 }
?>
```

ok, thats the first question

regarding my other question is just a question of security

Lets say I upload my pics with my script  connect.php but I dont want anoither people to interact with my script through my page, lets say I just want to make the connections private and secure, what should I do? make a REST API to handle connections more safe like serious apps?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Also, if not written then...just whatever? You really should have some kind of feedback for the user here.

Comment: yes i know about, the feedback, for the momment this is working as an example of a future implementation, im trying to know each error to fix it in the future and build a more strong code, thanks for the advice

Do you know how i can fix my first problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest problem is you can't save images based on the name the user gave you, this is a massive security problem, not to mention it lets one person stomp all your images if they want. You need to make up a random name for each upload, or base it on the record ID generated by your `INSERT` (e.g. `LAST_INSERT_ID()`) which should be unique so long as you never reset the `PRIMARY KEY` sequence.

It's also worth noting that HTTP multi-part uploads are the standard way to send in arbitrary file data. You're exposing yourself to a DDOS attack here if someone can send in payloads of unlimited size.

Comment: Thanks for the advide, yes i know is not secure the way im doing it, this is only for tetsing purposes, i will be doing some more secure connections in the future, so, back to the problem, it will be better that i save the pic of a user based on his ID ?  for example, user id: 1 , photo: image0001.jpg

and what about if the user wants to add more than 1 pic ?

Comment: Save it with the ID you get back from your `photos` table, not the user table.